# How to validate the return of a function based on conditional internal calls to other functions

Tags: php, design-patterns, boolean-logic

I have a function, as shown in the code below, that should return `true` if the code is executed correctly. Nothing new.

The problem is that the function calls other functions, each returns `true` or `false`.

I'm trying to figure out how to construct the logic to validate the output of the function checking the code of the function itself, and the returns of the other functions. The other functions might be called or not, depending on the `$this->conf['functionName']` parameter, which is also a boolean.

```
public function execute() {
    $return = false;
    if ($this->conf['functionOne']) {
        $this->functionOne();
    }
    if ($this->conf['functionTwo']) {
        $this->functionTwo();
    }
    if ($this->conf['functionThree']) {
        $this->functionThree();
    }
    return $return; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this

```
public function execute() {
    $function_list = ['functionOne', 'functionTwo', 'functionThree'];
    $return = true;
    foreach ($function_list as $function) {
        if ($this->conf[$function]) {
            if (!$this->{$function}() && $return) {
                $return = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Does your solution stop at the first false return? Why not to try to execute the other functions?

Comment: It depends on your business logic. Of course, you can try to execute other ones if you have to, but then... what would your execute() function should return in this case? For example, if f1, f2, f3 returned true, false, true - what would execute() return?

Comment: In your example the return of execute() is true, it only returns true if all the internal functions execute correctly.

Comment: By the way, I like your solution.

Comment: Updated my answer regarding to "it only returns true if all the internal functions execute correctly"

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear but I think you mean something like this...

```
public function execute() {

    $res1 = $res2 = $res3 = true;

    if($this->conf['functionOne']){
        $res1 = $this->functionOne();
    }

    if($this->conf['functionTwo']){
        $res2 = $this->functionTwo();
    }

    if($this->conf['functionThree']){
        $res3 = $this->functionThree();
    }

    return ($res1 && $res2 && $res3); 

}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need. The problem here is if then I need to include more functions, I'm not sure if `return ($res1 && $res2 && $res3 && ... && $resn);` is the best option.

Comment: I agree, it's lacking in flexibility. I'd go with Andreys answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

Is this works ?

```
public function execute() {

$f1 = $f2 = $f3 = false ;

if($this->conf['functionOne']){
    $f1 =  $this->functionOne();
}
if($this->conf['functionTwo']){
    $f2 = $this->functionTwo();
}
if($this->conf['functionThree']){
    $f3 = $this->functionThree();
}

if($f1=== true && $f2===true && $f3===true)
  return true;
else
  return false ;

}
```

Comment: No, because $this->conf['functionOne'] is different from $this->conf['functionTwo']. Each function is independent.

Comment: well when u call the function execute() it can return only one boolean how exactly you want to execute it ? U mean only one of the condition for conf will satisfy in each call ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your comment. The execution of every internal function depends on its own config parameter. Execute() only returns true if all of them where executed succesfully.

Comment: so u mean if any one of the internal function is false then Execute() will return false and if all of them are true then function will return true ?

Comment: and all the internal functions will execute in each call ?

Comment: No, it depends on the $this->conf['functionName'] parameter for each one.

Comment: Please check @Crisp's answer. Yours is similar and has the same problem regarding flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this:

```
public function execute() {

    $return = false;

    if($this->conf['functionOne']){
        $return = $this->functionOne();
    }
    if($this->conf['functionTwo']){
        $return = $this->functionTwo();
    }
    if($this->conf['functionThree']){
        $return = $this->functionThree();
    }
    return $return; 
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work if $this->conf['functionName'] is false for all of them or if the returns of the first and second functions is false and the return of the third one is true.